# ESS would no longer knit after upgrade to 14.09

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, ess

I downloaded in installed latest emacs and ess 14.09 from All-in-one installation file by Vincent Goulet. And now I can no longer knit my knitr documents. When I press M-n r is says "M-n r is undefined" and I don't see any options under ESS toolbar. I think the mode change - now it is Polymode. On polymode website weavers/exporters/tanglers are all under TODO. Does it mean it is not possible to knit under polymode?

Updates:
1) Make sure R starts in same folder where you knitr files are located (I don't think it mattered before)
2) Command for export is `M-n e` during first time it will ask you to set up weaver knitR-ESS - worked for me and knitR did not. (`M-n W` and `M-n E` allows you to set up weaver/exporter at any time)
3) It will also ask for exporter I use pdflatex. It successfully knited/weaved tex file. However pdf is not created. I receive a message

> ```
> Exporting 'car_analysis[weaved].tex' with 'pdflatex' exporter ...
> ```

and nothing happens. Any other options I am missing? I am on Windows with Miktex installed.